# snmp4j using snmpv3

Tags: authentication, snmp4j

I've, got a Problem by trying to Use SNMP v3 for my Project. Its difficult to Find Some Information’s About it so I tried my best by my own.
To Use SNMP v3 I Added a new USM User. now if got the Message when I’m Using a SNMP Walk that I’ve got no permissions do Read the MIBs. I’m sure I need to add the user to a Group, but I don’t know how.

The Error from the SNMPWalk[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjRBA.png)

```
UsmUser user = new UsmUser(new OctetString("admin"),
                        SnmpConstants.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                        new OctetString("root1234"),
                        null,
                        null);
                agent.getUsm().addUser(user.getSecurityName(), null, user);
                agent.getUsm().addUsmUserEntry(new UsmUserEntry(user.getSecurityName(),user));
          agent.getVacmMIB().addGroup(3,new OctetString("snmpV3"),new OctetString("V3User"),3);
              agent.getUsm().getUser(user.getLocalizationEngineID(),user.getSecurityName()).setOwnerReference(new UsmUserEntry(user.getSecurityName(),user));
```

[My Log after making the Request]

```Console
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Received message from /127.0.0.1/59863 with length 67: 30:41:02:01:03:30:0e:02:02:54:c3:02:02:05:dc:04:01:04:02:01:03:04:10:30:0e:04:00:02:01:00:02:01:00:04:00:04:00:04:00:30:1a:04:00:04:08:72:6f:6f:74:31:32:33:34:a5:0c:02:02:54:c3:02:01:00:02:01:14:30:00
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG SNMPv3 header decoded: msgId=21699, msgMaxSize=1500, msgFlags=04, secModel=3
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG RFC3414 §3.2.3 Unknown engine ID: ''
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Adding cache entry: StateReference[msgID=21699,pduHandle=PduHandle[1851516707],securityEngineID=,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=,securityLevel=1,contextEngineID=,contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Removed cache entry: StateReference[msgID=21699,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=,securityLevel=1,contextEngineID=,contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG RFC3414 §3.1.4.b Outgoing message is not encrypted
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Sending message to 127.0.0.1/59863 from 127.0.0.1/161 with length 102: 30:64:02:01:03:30:0f:02:02:54:c3:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:00:02:01:03:04:1d:30:1b:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:02:01:00:02:01:00:04:00:04:00:04:00:30:2f:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:04:00:a8:1c:02:01:00:02:01:00:02:01:00:30:11:30:0f:06:0a:2b:06:01:06:03:0f:01:01:04:00:41:01:17
2022-06-22 10:35:51.203 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Sending packet to 127.0.0.1/59863
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 INFO Dispatching message canceled due to security issue: statusInfo=1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.4.0 = 23, status=1410,tmStateReference=TransportStateReference[transport=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@754ba872, address=127.0.0.1/161, securityName=null, requestedSecurityLevel=undefined, transportSecurityLevel=undefined, sameSecurity=false, sessionID=java.net.DatagramSocket@47b55120, target=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Received message from /127.0.0.1/59863 with length 111: 30:6d:02:01:03:30:0f:02:02:54:c4:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:05:02:01:03:04:2e:30:2c:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:02:01:00:02:01:00:04:05:61:64:6d:69:6e:04:0c:79:37:01:02:c5:4d:b0:40:23:bb:0c:29:04:00:30:27:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:04:08:72:6f:6f:74:31:32:33:34:a0:0c:02:02:54:c4:02:01:00:02:01:00:30:00
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG SNMPv3 header decoded: msgId=21700, msgMaxSize=65535, msgFlags=05, secModel=3
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG getUser(engineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d, securityName=admin)
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG CheckTime: received message outside time window (authoritative):engineBoots differ 303!=0
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG RFC3414 §3.2.7.a Not in time window; engineID='80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d', engineBoots=0, engineTime=0
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Adding cache entry: StateReference[msgID=21700,pduHandle=PduHandle[1851516708],securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=admin,securityLevel=2,contextEngineID=,contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Removed cache entry: StateReference[msgID=21700,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=admin,securityLevel=2,contextEngineID=,contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.204 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG RFC3414 §3.1.4.b Outgoing message is not encrypted
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Sending message to 127.0.0.1/59863 from 127.0.0.1/161 with length 120: 30:76:02:01:03:30:0f:02:02:54:c4:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:01:02:01:03:04:2f:30:2d:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:02:02:01:2f:02:01:24:04:05:61:64:6d:69:6e:04:0c:17:43:76:cc:dc:8a:e9:ce:cc:7a:28:ba:04:00:30:2f:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:04:00:a8:1c:02:01:00:02:01:00:02:01:00:30:11:30:0f:06:0a:2b:06:01:06:03:0f:01:01:02:00:41:01:02
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Sending packet to 127.0.0.1/59863
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 INFO Dispatching message canceled due to security issue: statusInfo=1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0 = 2, status=1411,tmStateReference=TransportStateReference[transport=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@754ba872, address=127.0.0.1/161, securityName=null, requestedSecurityLevel=undefined, transportSecurityLevel=undefined, sameSecurity=false, sessionID=java.net.DatagramSocket@47b55120, target=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Received message from /127.0.0.1/59863 with length 129: 30:7f:02:01:03:30:0f:02:02:54:c5:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:05:02:01:03:04:2f:30:2d:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:02:02:01:2f:02:01:24:04:05:61:64:6d:69:6e:04:0c:6a:d6:67:0d:56:04:d2:af:02:18:1f:56:04:00:30:38:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:04:08:72:6f:6f:74:31:32:33:34:a5:1d:02:02:54:c5:02:01:00:02:01:14:30:11:30:0f:06:0b:2a:86:48:ce:16:82:2c:2b:01:01:01:05:00
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG SNMPv3 header decoded: msgId=21701, msgMaxSize=65535, msgFlags=05, secModel=3
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG getUser(engineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d, securityName=admin)
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG CheckTime: time ok (authoritative)
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG RFC3412 §7.2.10 - Received PDU is NOT a response or internal class message -> unchanged PduHandle = PduHandle[21701]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Adding cache entry: StateReference[msgID=21701,pduHandle=PduHandle[21701],securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=admin,securityLevel=2,contextEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,contextName=root1234,retryMsgIDs=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Fire process PDU event: CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=3, securityLevel=2, maxSizeResponsePDU=65363, pduHandle=PduHandle[21701], stateReference=StateReference[msgID=21701,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=admin,securityLevel=2,contextEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,contextName=root1234,retryMsgIDs=null], pdu=GETBULK[{contextEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d, contextName=root1234}, requestID=21701, errorStatus=0, errorIndex=20, VBS[1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1 = Null]], messageProcessingModel=3, securityName=admin, processed=false, peerAddress=127.0.0.1/59863, transportMapping=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@754ba872, tmStateReference=TransportStateReference[transport=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@754ba872, address=127.0.0.1/161, securityName=null, requestedSecurityLevel=undefined, transportSecurityLevel=undefined, sameSecurity=false, sessionID=java.net.DatagramSocket@47b55120, target=null]]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.205 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG No group found for secName 'admin' and secModel 3
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 INFO Request failed with VACM error 2: org.snmp4j.agent.request.SnmpRequest[phase=-1,errorStatus=0,source=CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=3, securityLevel=2, maxSizeResponsePDU=65363, pduHandle=PduHandle[21701], stateReference=StateReference[msgID=21701,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=admin,securityLevel=2,contextEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,contextName=root1234,retryMsgIDs=null], pdu=GETBULK[{contextEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d, contextName=root1234}, requestID=21701, errorStatus=0, errorIndex=20, VBS[1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1 = Null]], messageProcessingModel=3, securityName=admin, processed=true, peerAddress=127.0.0.1/59863, transportMapping=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@754ba872, tmStateReference=TransportStateReference[transport=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@754ba872, address=127.0.0.1/161, securityName=null, requestedSecurityLevel=undefined, transportSecurityLevel=undefined, sameSecurity=false, sessionID=java.net.DatagramSocket@47b55120, target=null]],response=null,transactionID=22,repeaterStartIndex=0,repeaterRowSize=1,reprocessCounter=0,subrequests=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG Created subrequest 0 with scope org.snmp4j.agent.DefaultMOContextScope[context=root1234,lowerBound=1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1,lowerIncluded=false,upperBound=null,upperIncluded=false] from 1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1 = Null
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG SnmpSubRequests initialized: [org.snmp4j.agent.request.SnmpRequest$SnmpSubRequest[scope=org.snmp4j.agent.DefaultMOContextScope[context=root1234,lowerBound=1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1,lowerIncluded=false,upperBound=null,upperIncluded=false],vb=1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1 = Null,status=RequestStatus{processed=false, phaseComplete=false, errorStatus=0},query=null,index=0,targetMO=null,lookupEvent=null]]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG Removed cache entry: StateReference[msgID=21701,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@31c88ec8,securityName=admin,securityLevel=2,contextEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d,contextName=root1234,retryMsgIDs=null]
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG RFC3414 §3.1.4.b Outgoing message is not encrypted
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG Sending message to 127.0.0.1/59863 from 127.0.0.1/161 with length 129: 30:7f:02:01:03:30:0f:02:02:54:c5:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:01:02:01:03:04:2f:30:2d:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:02:02:01:2f:02:01:24:04:05:61:64:6d:69:6e:04:0c:1e:23:b0:62:41:57:da:a8:fc:63:71:82:04:00:30:38:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:0a:c8:38:3d:46:a0:e5:9d:04:08:72:6f:6f:74:31:32:33:34:a2:1d:02:02:54:c5:02:01:10:02:01:01:30:11:30:0f:06:0b:2a:86:48:ce:16:82:2c:2b:01:01:01:05:00
2022-06-22 10:35:51.206 SNMPAgent.0 DEBUG Sending packet to 127.0.0.1/59863
java.lang.Exception: Error 'Authorization error' generated at: 1.2.840.10006.300.43.1.1.1 = Null
    at org.snmp4j.agent.request.SnmpRequest$SnmpSubRequest.requestStatusChanged(SnmpRequest.java:603)
    at org.snmp4j.agent.request.RequestStatus.fireRequestStatusChanged(RequestStatus.java:89)
    at org.snmp4j.agent.request.RequestStatus.setErrorStatus(RequestStatus.java:52)
    at org.snmp4j.agent.CommandProcessor.setAuthorizationError(CommandProcessor.java:485)
    at org.snmp4j.agent.CommandProcessor.processRequest(CommandProcessor.java:364)
    at org.snmp4j.agent.CommandProcessor.dispatchCommand(CommandProcessor.java:325)
    at org.snmp4j.agent.CommandProcessor$Command.run(CommandProcessor.java:575)
    at org.snmp4j.util.ThreadPool$TaskManager.run(ThreadPool.java:312)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
VacmMIB vacmMIB = agent.getVacmMIB();
vacmMIB.addGroup(SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_USM, user.getSecurityName(), new OctetString("v3group"), SnmpConstants.StorageTypeEnum.permanent.getSmiValue());
```